# Create video from still images

Tags: c#

I am developing an application that I can get series of Images from IP camera.

Now I want make video from those image. Can anyone help me in creating a video of any format from still images using C#?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) behind the scenes to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use ffmpeg, http://ffmpeg.org/

> FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.

Also...

> FFmpeg is free software licensed under the LGPL or GPL depending on your choice of configuration options. If you use FFmpeg or its constituent libraries, you must adhere to the terms of the license in question. You can find basic compliance information and get licensing help on our license and legal considerations page.

From the documentation:

```
For creating a video from many images:

ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi
```